# Gnome 3: Remove Workspace Number from Top Bar

Tags: gnome, gnome3

I use workspaces heavily, and I have another visual indicator in the top bar to tell me what workspace I am in.  By default Gnome has a number like in the screenshot below to show current workspace

The `2` is the element I want to remove
[image: top bar]

I do not need the default workspace indicator, however there does not seem to be a setting in Gnome Tweak Tool to disable it.

[This question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/163020/disable-workspace-switch-overlay-effect) pointed me towards an extension to disable the overlay effect, which was pretty annoying.  However I haven't found an extension that disables the workspace number, or settings anywhere.

Comment: That workspace indicator is not a default feature of Gnome 3. It's likely from an extension. Check your extensions in the Gnome Tweak Tool.

Comment: Yes, it was an extension "Workspace Indicator" (preinstalled with Debian-Gnome as far as I can tell).  Let this post stand as a testament to my own ignorance, and to aid anyone else in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The workspace indicator is not a built-in feature of the Gnome desktop. It is provided by the "Workspace Indicator" Gnome extension, which is pre-installed on some Linux distributions.

You can edit its settings or disable it entirely from the Gnome Tweak Tool's extensions section.